# Stop GPU core throttling in Acer V3-571G which makes graphics card useless

Tags: laptop, gpu, acer-aspire, throttling

I have bought Acer V3-571G it has GeForce GT630.Games are running superb... but just for a 2-3 minutes until this card warms up. I have updated BIOS from 1.08 to 1.13 and the memory stopped throttling but the core does **from 660mHz to 270mHz** and everything works horrible. What can I do about it.
This lowest result is during the game, it came back to middle 4xx mHz after I came back to dekstop, normal speed is 661,5  mHz. **It makes graphics card useless.**

It is common problem with Acer V3 the throttle temperature is set to too low value.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Gpu (and cpu for that matter) throttle for a variety of reasons. Most often it is because either the power was unplugged from the computer, or most likely in your case, if the temperature reaches a point that the computer feels is dangerous.

In the case of the temperature, try cleaning your vents. This happened to me before and after I cleaned all the lint and dust in the vents, it stopped throttleing

Comment: It is common problem with Acer V3 the throttle temperature is set to too low value.

Comment: It started in new laptop but just not in 3 minutes but like in 20.